# Python : Hash extension attack in python

Tags: python, md5

I want to use h to generate the same md5 as b

Here is the code:

```
k = "secret"
m = "show me the grade"
m2 = "show me the grade and change it to 100"
x = " and change it to 100"
a = md5(k + m)
b = md5(k + m2)
print "have---> " + a.hexdigest() #9f4bb32ac843d6db979ababa2949cb52
print "want---> " + b.hexdigest() #aba1d6fede83a87d9d6e22bf75974599

h = md5(state="9f4bb32ac843d6db979ababa2949cb52".decode("hex"),count=512)
h.update(x)

print h.hexdigest() # these two lines get 958acc96a173fd4d7571ac365db06f65
print md5((k + m + padding(len(k + m)*8))+ x).hexdigest()

def padding(msg_bits):
    """padding(msg_bits) - Generates the padding that should be
    appended to the end of a message of the given size to reach
    a multiple of the block size."""

    index = int((msg_bits >> 3) & 0x3f)
    if index < 56:
        padLen = (56 - index)
    else:
        padLen = (120 - index)

    # (the last 8 bytes store the number of bits in the message)
    return PADDING[:padLen] + _encode((msg_bits & 0xffffffffL, msg_bits>>32), 8)
```

I don't know why the last line couldn't output aba1d6fede83a87d9d6e22bf75974599. 
Is there something wrong with the padding?

Comment: We don't even know what you want, how should we be able to answer?

Comment: I want to use h to generate the MD5 equals to md5(k+m2)

Comment: That's a useful bit of information. Please read [ask] and try to specify what you expect, what you get instead, and what you want from us by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: what `padding` does? Also it could be helpful if you described a bit of what you trying to achieve ....

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hash you expected (aba1..) is the md5 hash of `k + m + x` while the hash you got (958a..) is the md5 hash of `k + m + padding + x`.

The length extension attack lets you generate a hash `h2 = md5(k + m + padding + x)` based on only knowing the hash `h1 = md5(k + m)` and the length of the message `l = len(k + m)`. However, as far as I know, it doesn't let you get rid of the padding between the messages, so you're left with some garbage in between.

Comment: So could u plz explain how to generate h2 with h1 and l?

Comment: As I said, as far as I know, you **can't** do it with a length extension attack. (And as far as I know, it isn't possible with any other method either; md5 may be broken, but as far as I know, it isn't yet broken enough that you could do a computationally feasible preimage attack on it)